# Extract data from multiple worksheets to one sheet using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook contain about 50 worksheets (sheet 1, sheet 2, sheet 3,........, sheet 50).

I want to get the data in all of them into one sheet. I used following code for that.

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet

    Set wsDest = Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> wsDest.Name Then
            'ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A22:Y500").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
            ws.Range("A12:Y60").Copy
            wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
        'ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Next ws

End Sub
```

But this code isn't working for all the sheets i have. it applies to random sheets.

What should i do to make it apply for all the sheets. (I have different rows in each sheet.)

And also above code runs for a long time.

Comment: You can probably speed up the process by turning off calculations: `Application.Calculation = xlManual` then swtch back to `xlAutomatic` when complete. What do you mean 'random sheets' ?  There's no pattern if run multiple times?

Comment: Some sample data is required here to make this answerable.

Comment: One possibility is that if some sheets don't have values in column A in the last row(s) being copied,  then the next sheets data will overwrite some of the just written data.

Answer (score -1):

The following code will consolidate data from all sheets in the workbook that is running the code.

Note that this is pasting just values (not formmating or formulas)

EDIT: Just for making this answer more clear. Using full qualifying of the target workbook and preventing to work with the active workbook, will guarantee that your looping through all the sheets. I address OPs request of looping through all sheets and not random ones. And also add a way to speed up the process.

Read the comments and adjust it to fit your needs:

```
Public Sub ConsolidateData()

    ' Declare and initialize the destination sheet
    Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
    Set destinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Loop through all worksheets in the workbook that is running the script
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    For Each sourceSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sourceSheet.Name <> destinationSheet.Name Then
            
            ' Set the source sheet's range
            Dim sourceRange As Range
            Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.UsedRange ' I'm using used range, but you could leave it as you had it in terms of a fixed range: sourceSheet.Range("A12:Y60").Copy
            
            ' Get first available cell in column A (from bottom to top)
            Dim targetCell As Range
            Set targetCell = destinationSheet.Range("A" & destinationSheet.Cells(destinationSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0)
            
            ' Resize and assign values from source range (using value2 speeeds up things)
            targetCell.Resize(sourceRange.Rows.Count, sourceRange.Columns.Count).Value2 = sourceRange.Value2
            
        End If
    Next sourceSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: This answer is not useful.   It's only a very slight refinement of the OPs posted code, and in no way address the OPs question (why their code doesn't work for all sheets)